# Stack Exchange site for code optimization

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can you post questions about optimizing code?

Like I want to post a question about a piece of C code I have written and then solicit input for how to make it execute faster on various platforms. Is there such a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think codereview.se would be a fit for that. Your code needs to work though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Code review is for open-ended improvements.  If the performance is not good enough, that's a known defect, and it would be on-topic for StackOverflow, not CR.

Comment: @BenVoigt If performance is not good enough, then it can be off-topic on both SO and CR. I can't exactly speak for why or when SO vote to close it, but I have not seen any questions being closed on CR for asking about how to improve the performance.